# laravel 5 environment configuration

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, environment-variables

I'm migrating a Laravel 4 site to 5.2, and struggling with environment configuration.

My L4 site has quite a few config files (i.e. */app/config/staging/constants.php*), all of which vary according to environment: endpoint urls, 3rd party service credentials, all sorts of integration values. There's probably a couple hundred settings in all, and they way they're split across files and stored in PHP arrays makes them pretty easy to manage.

Moving these into - as I understand it - the single key-value format of an .env file is going to result in an unwieldy mess.

At the moment, I'm thinking to move my current L4 */app/config* folders and files into the new L5 */config* folder, and just change the way I reference them, to e.g:

`$value = config(App::environment() . '.constants.some.value');`

However, this strikes me as something which, if it were a good idea (and assuming it even works), would have been suggested in the docs.

So.. am I missing something here? What's the best way to manage a large number of environment-specific values in a meaningful data structure in Laravel 5?

Comment: In L5, if you have `/config/my_config.php` file, you can "import" it using `app/bootstrap.php`. In `app/bootstrap.php` simply add `$app->configure('my_config')` and `config/my_config.php` will be added to configuration. To pull stuff out, `config('my_config.key_name');`. Hope that helps a bit, basically you don't have to spend too much time on migrating from one version to another, and you don't have to waste time on `.env`.

Comment: That is really useful to know, thanks - although I'm still a bit confused about how I'd automatically pull in the correct config file for the environment. Do you mean something like `$app->configure(App::environment() . '.my_config')` ?

Comment: Exactly, something like that. :)

Comment: Just a side note, maybe you knew, maybe you didn't: `env('APP_ENV');` -> now you can pull certain keys from `.env`, if you opt to even use it.

Comment: Awesome. Have an upvote.

Comment: You could clear the files under `config/` and then use them as a proxy to require the desired config file depending on `env('APP_ENV');`
e.g. in `config/app.php`: `if(env('APP_ENV') === 'production)) { require_once('config/production/app.php'); ...`